# how to change color primary text , and color navigation

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

How to change the color of dial . Pay attention not color primary variant , and how to change the color on of button of navigation , not navigation bar color .

from this picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKfB8.jpg)

to that picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pswxW.jpg)

sorry for bad english, I'm from Ukraine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the text has changed but the navigation buttons no i found a better solution via xml for text

`<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>`

all that remains is to change the navigation buttons, not their background

but still thank you this answer helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

`decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(decorView.getSystemUiVisibility() | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);` will change the color of the icons .. however if you want to support the dark theme you would need `decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(decorView.getSystemUiVisibility() & ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);`